# How to color an input box without generating an inset effect

Tags: html, css

I notice that if you give an input element a background-color the appearance of the box changes to include an inset effect.

CSS:

```
input#input1 {
}
input#input2 {
    background-color:white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="input1" value ="1">
<input id="input2" value ="2">
```

Is there a way to color the background of an input box without getting this inset effect?

Reference URL :  http://jsfiddle.net/aBus6/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding your own border to it will fix that:

```
  border-color:grey;
  border-width:1px;
  padding:2px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to overide the default css that the browser is adding eg

```
input#input2 { 
  background-color:white; 
  border:none;
  box-shadow: 0;
}
```

If you inspect the element you should be able to see all styling being added by the browser.

Comment: I'm looking at input2 in my jsfiddle, using Firebug, but I'm not seeing the box-shadow style added by the browser.

Comment: There's an outline offset being added by the browser, set this to 0
`outline-offset: 0;`